# The Constructor is undefined? Enum error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public Tipo getTipo() {
    return this.Importo < 0.0 ? Tipo.USCITA : Tipo.ENTRATA;
}

public int compareTo(Movimento m) {
    if (this.idConto != this.idConto) {
        return this.idConto - this.idConto;
    }
    return this.DataMov.compareTo(this.DataMov);
}

public static enum Tipo {
    ENTRATA,// here i have this error : The constructor Movimento.Tipo() is undefined
    USCITA;// here is the same : The constructor Movimento.Tipo() is undefined


    private Tipo(String string2, int n2) {
    }
}
```

I already have constructor that I need, what else I need to write?

Comment: You wrote a constructor that takes two arguments, but no default constructor.  That means the compiler will not provide a no-arg constructor.  You should provide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how do you want to define enum. There are basically 2 solutions to this:

**1. Define no parameter enum**

```
public static enum Tipo {
    ENTRATA,
    USCITA;
}
```

**2. Define enum with parameters**

```
public static enum Tipo {
    ENTRATA("Entrata", 1),
    USCITA("Uscita", 2);

    private String string;
    private int integer;

    private Tipo(String string, int integer) {
        this.string = string;
        this.integer = integer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a constructor that takes two arguments, but no default constructor.  That means the compiler will not provide a no-arg constructor.  You should provide one or remove the private constructor.

I see no reason for the private constructor with two arguments.  You don't have any private data members in your enum.

Why is your enum static?  Remove that.

```
public enum Tipo {
    ENTRATA, USCITA;

}
```

Comment: It's quite a challenge for OP to write a default constructor, since he's no compiler.

Comment: I assume this is his code.  The code that I posted will have a no-arg constructor.  I don't understand this comment.

Comment: You wrote *"You wrote a constructor that takes two arguments, but no default constructor. That means the compiler will not provide a no-arg constructor."*, but it is the other way around. The constructor won't create a **default** constructor, because OP defined his own one. So OP need to create the **no-arg** constructor.

Comment: Default and no arg are the same thing.  I know what he needs.  That's what I said.

Comment: They do the same (if the "no arg" has an empty body), but they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are written wrong enum.

```
public enum abc {

    ENTRATA("abc", 1),// here i have this error : The constructor Movimento.Tipo() is undefined
    USCITA("xyz", 2);// here is the same : The constructor Movimento.Tipo() is undefined


    private abc(String string2, int n2) {
    }
```

}

Comment: if you have 2 argument constructor in enum then enum variable contain two arguments because each variable in enum acts as an object.